# How can I speed up my array search with an NSPredicate?

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

I have an array of categories, and another array of category IDs.  I want to pull out the categories with matching IDs.  At the moment, my code looks a bit like this:

```
- (NSArray *)categoriesFromArray:(NSArray *)categories withIDs:(NSArray *)categoryIDs {
    NSMutableArray *categoriesWithIDs = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (SGBCategory *category in categories) {
        for (NSNumber *categoryID in categoryIDs) {
            if ([category.categoryID isEqual:categoryID]) {
                [categoriesWithIDs addObject:category];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return categoriesWithIDs;
}
```

Ewww, I know.  So what I'd like to do is something like `SELECT * FROM categories WHERE categories.categoryID in (categoryIDs)` does in SQL.  I think NSPredicate is the objective-c way of expressing that sort of thing, but I don't know how to get it to do what I want.  How can I speed up my array search with an NSPredicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return [categories filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"categoryID IN %@", categoryIDs]];
```

I don't know that it will be any faster, though. It basically has to do the same sort of thing as your code, plus build a predicate.

You can improve your code by making an `NSSet` from the `categoryIDs` and using `-containsObject:` instead of looping over the `categoryIDs` and calling `-isEqual:` manually.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the predicate thing but an immediate optimisation is to put your category ids in a set

```
- (NSArray *)categoriesFromArray:(NSArray *)categories withIDsFromSet:(NSSet *)categoryIDs {
    NSMutableArray *categoriesWithIDs = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (SGBCategory *category in categories) {
        if ([categoryIDS containsObject: [category categoryID]])
        {
            [categoriesWithIDs addObject:category];
        }
    }
    return categoriesWithIDs;
}
```

**Edit**

If you want to continue using your old method, modify it thusly:

```
- (NSArray *)categoriesFromArray:(NSArray *)categories withIDs:(NSArray *)categoryIDs {

    return [self categoriesFromArray: categories withIDsFromSet: [NSSet setWithArray: categoryIDs]];
}
```

This will still be vastly more efficient than your original method provided either `categories` or `categoryIDs` is largish.

Comment: Thanks - though that changes the signature of the method, so it's not workable for us.

Comment: @Simon: it's a new method, so it's not changing the signature.  However, I'll modify my answer a bit to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSPredicate* searchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"categoryID == %f", categoryID];
    NSArray *categoriesWithIDs =[categories filteredArrayUsingPredicate:searchPredicate];
    return categoriesWithIDs;
```

This is how you would do what you want i think. Assuming that the category id is a float. change the %f as needed, just as you would with NSLog.